# Why are these values not appending correctly when appended to the pipeline?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a bash script (seen [here](https://github.com/plushu/plushu/blob/bashbug/lib/plushook)) that I'm using to sort a list of files in subdirectories by filename.

This script appends sorted files in `hooks/pre-relevant/`, then files *named* `hooks/pre-relevant`, then files named `hooks/relevant`, then sorted files in `hooks/relevant/`, using the `append_hook` function below:

```
hooks=()

# Run a hook script, if it's executable, with the input from this invocation
append_hook () {
  if [[ -f "$1" && -x "$1" ]]; then
    hooks+=("$1")
  fi
}
```

I'm testing it with this directory structure:

```
testing-range/plugins/
|-- bar
|   `-- hooks
|       |-- irrelevant
|       |-- only-one
|       `-- relevant
|-- dickory
|   `-- hooks
|       `-- pre-relevant
|-- doc
|   `-- hooks
|       |-- perl-envsubst
|       `-- relevant
|           |-- 00
|           `-- 20
|
|-- factory
|   `-- hooks
|       `-- relevant
`-- hickory
    `-- hooks
        |-- pre-relevant
        |   `-- 30
        `-- relevant
            `-- 10
```

When I use this multi-step array code to append the files:

```
append_numbered_hooks () {
  # Gather every file into an array, prefixing each item with the
  # filename of the script (its position in sort order)
  local filelist=()
  for hook in "$PLUSHU_ROOT"/plugins/*/hooks/"$hookname"/*; do
    filelist+=("${hook##*/}/$hook")
  done

  # Sort the array numerically
  printf '%s\0' "${filelist[@]}" | sort -nz | IFS= read -rd '' -a filelist

  # Append each script in sorted order
  for hookline in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    append_hook "${hookline#*/}"
  done
}
```

I get *almost* the correct output:

```
hickory/hooks/pre-relevant/30
dickory/hooks/pre-relevant
bar/hooks/relevant
factory/hooks/relevant
doc/hooks/relevant/00
doc/hooks/relevant/20
hickory/hooks/relevant/10
```

Yet, when I append the files using this simpler pipeline:

```
append_numbered_hooks () {
  for hook in "$PLUSHU_ROOT"/plugins/*/hooks/"$1"/*; do
    printf '%s\0' "${hook##*/}/$hook"
  done | sort -nz | while IFS= read -rd '' hookline; do
    append_hook "${hookline#*/}"
  done
}
```

The numbered files don't show up in a for "${hooks[@]}" loop:

```
dickory/hooks/pre-relevant
bar/hooks/relevant
factory/hooks/relevant
```

What's going on? The correct values should be:

```
hickory/hooks/pre-relevant/30
dickory/hooks/pre-relevant
bar/hooks/relevant
factory/hooks/relevant
doc/hooks/relevant/00
hickory/hooks/relevant/10
doc/hooks/relevant/20
```

Comment: Process substitution is almost always a workaround for a badly ordered process. `set -- "$PLUSHU_ROOT"/*/hook[s]/*relevant/[0-9]*[0-9]; while [ -n "$1" ]; do [ -z "${1##*/hook\[*}" ] || env - "$1" ; shift; done` should be pretty close to what you need, though maybe you have to sort it first. But that's easily done, because all of the returns are in your shell `"$@"` array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell

So, you are altering a variable in a subshell. When the subshell exits, those alterations vanish.

You may find [process substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) helpful.

```
append_numbered_hooks () {
  while IFS= read -rd '' hookline; do
    append_hook "${hookline#*/}"
  done < <(
    for hook in "$PLUSHU_ROOT"/plugins/*/hooks/"$1"/*; do
      printf '%s\0' "${hook##*/}/$hook"
    done | 
    sort -nz
  )
}
```

Comment: If that's the case, then why does the first approach (which also reads in a pipeline) work just fine?

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley, your `printf '%s\0' "${filelist[@]}" | sort -nz | IFS= read -rd '' -a filelist` does nothing, because the `read` updates the `$filelist` of a subshell. Possibly your `filelist` was alread sorted (globs do sort)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas hah, good point- it actually wasn't sorted (the correct sort value I listed was [PICNIC](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PICNIC) noise)!

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley, note that you can also use `zsh` or `ksh93` instead of `bash` which don't have the problem (and `zsh` has many interesting features you could make use of like builtin ways of numerically sorting lists (`filelist=(${(on)filelist})`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You can also use `shopt -s lastpipe` in Bash: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024